# Loudicrouz.J virus in visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I was making a simple Console based C++ application and made a loading bar using Visual Studio 2017. I encountered an error having a prompted message that my code contains potentially bugs or viruses. Microsoft Security detects it as **Torjan:Win32/Loudicrouz.J (severe)**.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

class loading_bar {
    int loading_percentage;
    int loading_per_increment;
public:
    loading_bar();
    void print_loading_bar();
    void delay(int);
};

void loading_bar::delay(int milliseconds)
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    while ((clock() - start) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC < milliseconds) {

    }
}

loading_bar::loading_bar() {
    loading_percentage = 0;
    loading_per_increment = 1;
}

void loading_bar::print_loading_bar() {
    for (; loading_percentage < 50; loading_percentage++) {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\n\n\n\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t";
        cout << "--------------------------------------------------\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t";
        cout << "|";
        for (int i = 0; i < loading_percentage; i++) {
            cout << char(219);
        }
        for (int j = 49 - loading_percentage;j>0; j--) {
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "|\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t";
        cout << "--------------------------------------------------\n";
        delay(100 / loading_per_increment);
    }
}
```

Though my code is working fine and still I don't know what's the reason behind this virus. I was unable to find the issue where it's been caused.

Comment: Can you use `Sleep(milliseconds)` in your `delay` function (comment its existing body) and then see what happens?

Comment: OK. let me check this

Comment: The problem have been resolved but still I don't know what was the issue.

Comment: Most probably, your antivirus runs your executable in a sandbox environment and observes its behavior. The clock stuff using the loop in the code triggers some rule of the antivirus detection mechanism that this might be suspicious as the code is waiting for a particular time to execute some malicious stuff. Using the `Sleep` function didn't trigger it so now it's resolved. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it helped me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210922/discussion-between-ghazanfar-ateeb-and-azeem).

Comment: I've found this [thread](https://mlog.club/article/5446286) and the code is exactly the same. And, it was posted at about the same time. Did you post this or copy the code from?

Comment: Another [thread](https://answers.opencv.org/question/228460/ludicrouzj-trojan-detected-in-built-exe/) having the same issue involving OpenCV and VS2017. Did you try to run your program with any other VS version? If you have another version of VS, can you try to compile your older code with that one? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `delay()` method might be the culprit where you're waiting in the loop:

```
void loading_bar::delay(int milliseconds)
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    while ((clock() - start) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC < milliseconds) {

    }
}
```

Replace it with `Sleep()` like this:

```
void loading_bar::delay(int milliseconds)
{
    Sleep( milliseconds );
}
```

Most probably, your antivirus runs your executable in a sandbox environment and observes its behavior i.e. API calls. That waiting in the loop triggers some rule of the antivirus detection mechanism that this might be suspicious as the code is waiting for a particular time to execute some malicious stuff. Using the `Sleep()` function didn't trigger it so now it's resolved. I hope it helps!

Comment: Do you have any reference that explains, why a busy wait would trigger potentially malicious activities?

Comment: @IInspectable: What I meant is that a pattern of WinAPI calls causes the application to trigger a rule resulting in flagging the app as malicious. The waiting for some time/date is generally is a common one. Antiviruses are usually closed-source applications. Sure. I'll look for some references and add them to my answer. Some YARA rules might also be available to reference here.

Comment: There aren't any Windows API calls in the busy wait loop, with the exception of querying the system clock (likely implemented as a call to `GetTickCount`). Are you suggesting, that any AV suite would flag consecutive calls to the system clock as a potential threat based on that behavior? I doubt that your observation (or explanation) is accurate. It's **way** more likely for the code to compile into a sequence of bytes - by coincidence only - that happens to match the signature of known malware.

Comment: @IInspectable: I guess my explanation was not clear. Sorry about that. Signatures are an easy part to detect known malware under static malware analysis. I was referring to the dynamic malware analysis where the behavioral patterns are observed and flagged. Looking at the code, the first natural hint for me was to explore that time thing. And, the proper analysis `Torjan:Win32/Loudicrouz.J (severe)`, how it matches the OP's executable and why Microsoft Security flagged it would definitely reveal more relevant information.